# java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: groovy

In my groovy application, I receive a java.sql.Timestamp object using Hibernate createCriteria(), and I want to convert it into java.util.Date object. I tried the following codes below but to no avail:

```
Date javaDateObject = sqlDateObject
Date javaDateOject = (Date)sqlDateObject
Date javaDateObject = sqlDateObject as Date
```

I get the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
  Cannot cast object '[Ljava.lang.Object;@14a4864' with class 
  '[Ljava.lang.Object;' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

Comment: No, an *array* of objects cannot be cast to a date--which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
Date javaDateObject = new Date(sqlDateObject.time)
```

Comment: Did it work to you? If so, please mark as correct the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since sqlDateObject is actually a Object[] and not a java.sql.Timestamp the error is normal.

Assuming the array contains the Timestamp as (single) first element, you can of course do `Date javaDateOject = (Date) sqlDateObject[0]` (or the variant with "as"). But since Timestamp is a subclass of Date, this does actually do nothing.

If you really need a Date then I suggest to do this:

```
Date javaDateOject = new Date(sqlDateObject[0].time)
```